# hash() function in mysql version 8.0

Tags: mysql, hash, passwords

I am trying to store passwords in my user table. Of course I want to salt and hash them before.

But there's no hash() method in mysql anymore. How can I do it in version 8.0? Are there alternatives?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Please include the *exact* error message, not some approximation of it. MySQL does not have a general `HASH()` function. You may be confusing it with the [`HASH()` partitioning method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-linear-hash.html).

Comment: And in addition to not having a `hash`-function, MySQL 8.0.11+ does not have a [password()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)-function anymore either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hash passwords in your app, before sending them to SQL.

Why do I say this? After all you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO Accounts (user, salt, password) 
VALUES ('myuser', '1234', SHA2(CONCAT('xyzzy', '1234'), 256))
```

But now you the password 'xyzzy' appears in plain-text in your query logs and binary logs, even if it is stored in hashed form in the table itself. If you don't secure your logs adequately, a hacker could get a hold of them and find everyone's password.

Instead, perform the hash operation in your application code. Get the result of that, and save the hash string verbatim in the database.

```
INSERT INTO Accounts (user, salt, password) 
VALUES ('myuser', '1234', 'd3822b5f03ad0c1a363d874238f6b48fd68a131cc35d5e55c77a81db1d266b84')
```

That way the plain-text password does not get logged.

Likewise, when you do password checks for users as they log in, read the salt, then use it to hash the password they input, then compare that to the hash string stored in the database.

```
SELECT salt FROM Accounts WHERE user = ?

...calculate hash string using user input + salt...

SELECT password = ? AS password_matches FROM Accounts WHERE user = ?
```